# how to keep old data record while updating asp .net mvc 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework-6

I am creating a financial application using with `Asp .net mvc5 with EF6`.I have a big puzzle about updating database. What I want is that I have `Person` table `(e.g. firstname, lastname, address, salary, tax, and so on)`. For the first time, I entered a record `(e.g. John, Smith, US, 3500.00,)`. When `John Smith` gets promotion, I will update his salary as `4000.00` while I am still wanting to keep his old salary `3500.00`. If I don't keep his `3500.00`, his `tax` and `other deductible` fees from his `3500.00` salary won't `reflect correctly` upto the last day that he earned `3500.00`. Data of his tax all along getting `3500.00` will lose and will reflect based on `4000.00`.

Can anyone guide me on how to solve this, please? Appreciate if you can share any resources or links that I can study for this kind of problem. Thank in advance.

Comment: You need an additional table (say Salaries) containing fields for the PersonID, Date and Salary details

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a table corresponding to the main table `Person` lets call it `Person_log` `(e.g. firstname, lastname, address, salary, tax,Entry_Date_On_Log and so on)`

> Process 1:

create a trigger for insert,update and insert record to the `Person_log` table on insert and every update on `Person` table.

> Process 2:

you can manually(using query code) enter the records to the `Person_log` table on every and each entry to the  `Person` table.

> Now, whenever you want to calculate the Tax or anything else
>   corresponding to a date for a Person, you can easily find the Salary
>   or any other records for a Person from `Person_log` table using the
>   Date filter(`Entry_Date_On_Log`).

Comment: I also recommend @user3540365's answer. That way the heavy work will be on the SQL SERVER.

Comment: are you two suggesting to use timestamp? Thank for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

except user3540365 suggested method there are 2 more methods

**Method 1**

use of  Change Data Capture (SQL Server)

you can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx)

**Method 2**

you can create a log table and use output clause

read more about output clause [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

i would say go for method 1 it is really easy